# How can I start multiple programs at once?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0

if I got 2 Main methods, how do i play both at once? Because when I play it now, it just gives me an error that says: "Program has more than one entry point defined." Then asks me to pick a main, but is there a way where I dont have to pick one and instead run both?

here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Case1Fodbold
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("indtast antal af afleveringer ");
            int Afleveringer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Mål eller ej");
            string MålCheck = Console.ReadLine();
            string mÅL = "Mål";
            string Output1;

            if (mÅL.Equals(MålCheck, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Olé olé olé");
            }
            else if (Afleveringer == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Shhh.");
            }
            else if (Afleveringer > 9)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("High Five - Jubel!!!");
            }
            else
            {
                Output1 = "Huh! ";
                while (i < Afleveringer)
                {
                    Output1 = Output1 + "Huh! ";
                    i = i + 1;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(Output1);

                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }

    namespace OperatorOvlApplication
    {
        class DancePoints
        {
            private string navn;
            private int point;

            public DancePoints(string navn, int point)
            {
                this.navn = navn;
                this.point = point;
            }
            // This is automatically called when '+' is used with
            // between two Complex objects
            public static DancePoints operator +(DancePoints obj, DancePoints obj2)
            {
                DancePoints res = new DancePoints(default, default);
                res.point = obj.point + obj2.point;
                res.navn = obj.navn + " & " + obj2.navn;
                return res;
            }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return this.navn + " " + this.point;
            }
        };
        class Tester
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Skriv den første navn");
                String FørstePersonNavn = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Skriv den første score");
                int FørstePersonPoint = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Skriv det andet navn");
                String AndenPersonNavn = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Skriv den anden score");
                int AndenPersonPoint = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                DancePoints FørstePerson = new DancePoints(FørstePersonNavn, FørstePersonPoint);
                DancePoints AndenPerson = new DancePoints(AndenPersonNavn, AndenPersonPoint);
                DancePoints KombineretScore = FørstePerson + AndenPerson;
                Console.WriteLine(KombineretScore);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if anyone finds my question incomprehensible or dont understand it. English isn't my first language also I have a hard time formulating myself.

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to do? As the error tells you, you cannot have multiple "Main-methods", So you might either want to take a parameter that makes your program do different things, or create two different programs.

Comment: In a _Solution_ you can have several _Projects_ of which each can have its own `Main()` (depending on project type). You then can set either one of them or several of them as "Start Project".

Comment: As mentioned, you cant have 2 Main's in a single project. Each project has its own namespace, you will not be able to put a namespace(project) inside another namespace(project).
Since you are danish and have a new account, i would think that you are still in school, try asking your teacher about what @Fildor mentioned. Although, i dont think that was what your assignment was, so i would recommend you asking your teacher what he meant with the assignment instead and get him to explain you how you can do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Unrelated: I'd also recommend to stick with ASCII chars for variable names.

Comment: And for the heck of me I cannot comprehend why they teach to use `Convert`. It's quick and cheap, yes. But people actually think that's what you should be using in production code. _It's not_. It _will_ crash your App on some unexpected input by the first user that's not you. Use for example `int.TryParse` instead.

Comment: @Fildor, dont worry about that, i think i know where he goes to school, not a lot of places where they teach to write like this. And this is first year/"just starting to learn". They will learn it later or - even more likely - drop out.

Comment: @RatzMouse Coming from a Martial Arts background, I know what it means to having adopted bad style that you struggle to "unlearn" as soon as you know better. That's probably why stuff like that triggers me so hard. :D

Answer (score 0):

Usually we don't write two main methods on one program. But you can also achieve the effect you want by following the steps below.
Project -> (your Project name)+Properties -> Application -> General -> strat object -> Case1Fodbold.Program
[image]

[image]

Then add the following code in the following location：

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("indtast antal af afleveringer ");
 
 
            Tester.Main(args);//code to add
 
            int Afleveringer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Mål eller ej");
            string MålCheck = Console.ReadLine();
            string mÅL = "Mål";
            string Output1;
```